PSoC 4100S calibration / layout issues
I hope someone can help me with my issue calibrating the PSoC 4100S CY8C4126AXI-S433 chips.
I’m trying to calibrate a CSD slider from 0 to 100 (8-bit), but so far, I haven’t been successful with either auto-calibration or manual calibration.
For testing, I’m using the mtb-example-psoc4-capsense-buttons-and-slider-rtt example in ModusToolbox. Each chip is connected to 24 pads configured as a CSD linear slider.
When using Full Auto-Tune mode (finger capacitance set to 0.1 pF), all sensors are not responsible and in a high state, except sens 10 (11th pin) .


Pin 11 is close to the PSOC IC.
Board itself is 4 layer board:
1-GND plane and Components and routs, 2-PWR, 3-Hatched GND, 4 GND and Sensor pads.
General view:

Close view:

I tried to use different calibration settings (Manual, Auto-tune, and Hardware auto-tune)
But results a quite the same, so I'm assuming there might be a hardware/layout issue.
Maybe I need to add resistors between pads and PSOC pins or change default Hi-Z mode?
Here is my schematic:

In general I have 9 PSOCs on the board, and now testing 1st PSOC, connected via KitProg3 SWD.
Hope that someone can provide some tips how to make it work.
And thank you in advance.
